# Content not displaying until effect over

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, accordion, easing-functions

I have an application whit accordion

```
<mx:Accordion minHeight="200" includeIn="radegund0" top="10" bottom="10" left="10" right="10" openDuration="2000" openEasingFunction="{Elastic.easeOut}">
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--content1-->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--content2-->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:Accordion>
```

but when click on the second tab for the first time the content is not shown until the effect is over. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers with multiple views, such as the ViewStack and Accordion, do not immediately create all of their descendants, but only those descendants that are visible in the initial view. Flex defers the creation of descendants that are not initially visible until the user navigates to a view that contains them, which is what's happening here.  Set `creationPolicy="all"` on the Accordian, to create all controls in all views of the Accordian from the start.